# Looking for a list of service accounts that have read or write ability in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, service-accounts

I am looking for a list of service accounts that have read or write ability in AD.

If all of the service accounts have that ability, then I might be looking for service accounts that query active directory often instead. I would like this in a PowerShell script. I'm trying to add the data into Description column in the CSV file.

```
# Define input and output paths
$ServiceAccountFile = "C:\main\ServiceAccounts.txt"
$CsvPath = "C:\main\ServiceAccountsInfo.csv"

# Read service account names from the text file
try {
    $ServiceAccounts = Get-Content -Path $ServiceAccountFile -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to read service account file: $_"
    exit 1
}

# Process each service account
$ServiceAccountInfo = $ServiceAccounts | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing service account: $_"

    # Your custom logic here (e.g., granting permissions, retrieving additional info)
    # For demonstration purposes, let's create a sample object with account name and description
    $AccountInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        AccountName = $_
        Description = "Some description"  # Replace with actual data
        # Add more properties as needed
    }

    $AccountInfo
}

# Export service account information to a CSV file
try {
    $ServiceAccountInfo | Export-Csv -Path $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Service account information exported to $CsvPath"
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to export service account information: $_"
}
```

Comment: to know what rights an identity has in active directory you need to analyze the acls of active directory and compare this information with the identity and also for the groups the identity is assigned to. in principle any domain joined identity has read. to know if an identity does often query AD you would have to activate the ldap debug logs and parse that information - but those logs generate a huge load of data...